# Proving the ring of formal power series over a finite field is integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain, formal-power-series

Yes so my question shown in the first image;

I would like to prove that the ring of formal power series over the finite field of order prime, s is an integral domain.

[image]

[image]

So if it is not clear the first image is the question in its entirety and page 1 of my working out and the 2nd image is also my working out.

If anyone could verify my work, or tell me if I have got it all wrong lol it would be welcome.

-nomad609

Comment: okay sorry, for further questions I will upload the problem written and attach a written solution if that is okay? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: The images are no longer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question can be done much easier by proving the converse:
$$
fg\neq0 \iff f\neq0 \land g\neq0\tag1
$$
where $f,g\in K[[x]]$, $K$ is finite field of order $p$.

Let $a_0$ be constant of $f$ and $b_0$ be constant of $g$. Clearly $a_0b_0$ is constant of $fg$ and 
$$
p|a_0b_0\iff p|a_0 \lor p|b_0\quad\text{or}\quad p\nmid a_0b_0\iff p\nmid  a_0 \land p\nmid b_0
$$
This means
$$
(a_0b_0\not\equiv0\mod p) \iff (a_0\not\equiv0\mod p)\land (b_0\not\equiv0 \mod p)
$$
So $(1)$ follows.

Comment: Ah very nice, I like your method :) Thank you for sharing. May I ask you if my method is also acceptable - obviously yours is prefered, but just trying to consolidate in this area.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. May I ask you elucidate what you mean please. Shoudl I just follow what you did instead - or instead just merge the two ideas together. I am unsure because your method seems cleaner. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You try to prove it directly through $fg=0\iff f=0\lor g=0$, which is ok. But  in this way you have to prove all coefficients of $fg$ are $0$, which clearly takes more steps.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thanks :L

Comment: Certainly. Kind Regards