# Proving ring of FPS is not a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, integral-domain, formal-power-series

Following on from my question of the proof of the ring of a FPS is an integral domain:

[Proving the ring of formal power series over a finite field is integral domain.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025985/proving-the-ring-of-formal-power-series-over-a-finite-field-is-integral-domain/)

I would like to extend to that to finding a proof of showing that **the ring of formal power series over a finite field of order prime is not a field.**

Just confused really, with proving it was an integral domain, it seemed to be fine.

Thanks for any help

-nomad609

Comment: How do you invert an element of zero constant term that is nonzero? (for a specific example, think of the formal power series of sine).

Comment: The ring of formal power series in *never* a field. Can you find a non-invertible element?

Comment: I would think that it would be when the denominator of some constant is non-zero

Comment: Or perhaps if we were to have some constant, not equal to 0 over a field then that would also be invertible.

Comment: Sorry English isn't my 1st language. I read it is invertible. If it were non-invertible then if we had (a+b) where a and b are both elements which belong to the same ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find a noninvertible element, as the comments suggest, or you could (equivalently) find a nonzero ideal that isn't the whole ring itself. Consider the homomorphism
\begin{align*}
\phi : k[\![T]\!]&\to k\\
\sum_{i = 0}^\infty a_i T^i&\mapsto a_0.
\end{align*}
The homomorphism above is clearly surjective, and it's not hard to verify that the kernel is $(T)$. In a field, the only ideals are $(0)$ and $(1)$. But $(0)\subsetneq (T)\subsetneq (1)$ ($T\not\in (0)$, and $1\not\in (T)$, because $\phi(1) = 1$), so $k[\![T]\!]$ cannot be a field.

Comment: An excellent point, which I had not considered. Thank you.